# Is there a way to store some files in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, online-storage

I'd like to store some files in Gmail, in order to easily attach them to letters, without the need to upload them over and over again. Maybe you know of such a service? Of course there are always file hosters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Docs provides the facility to store files of any<sup>1</sup> type by uploading them to Google Docs. From there it would be possible to email the files appending the letter text you also wanted to include into the email.

It is also possible to directly link to a file stored in Google Docs, but you might find people can't access the link due to system restrictions on which website they can access and etc.

<sub>1. I don't think this includes **.exe** files, unfortunately.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Mail the files to yourself, then forward it to the person you want to send it to - you can edit the title and add whatever you need.

Comment: I think this is your best option if you all you ever plan on doing with the files is emailing them to others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux, you can use [gmailfs](http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem.html) or [imapfs](http://imapfs.sourceforge.net/), but you have to use the IMAP protocol and not the POP3 to access the mail server.

I don't know if there are other similar solutions for Windows, but you can easily check it on

Comment: I'm trying to make [gmailfs](http://sr71.net/projects/gmailfs/) work.

Comment: Failed to make use of `gmailfs` for my needs (attaching files).